# Examples of semigroups of contractive Fourier multipliers but not positive?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, fourier-series, lp-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Can you show me a concrete an example of semigroup $(T_t)_{t\geq 0}$ of [Fourier multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplier_%28Fourier_analysis%29) such that each operator $T_t$ induces a contractive Fourier multiplier  $T_t\colon L^p(\mathbb{T}) \to L^p(\mathbb{T})$ for any $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ and such that $(T_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a $C_0$-semigroup of self-adjoint contractive operators on $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ *but* such that $(T_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is *not* a semigroup of *positive* operators (in the sense that it maps positive functions into positive functions)?

Comment: It is known that an isometric Fourier multiplier is a scalar multiple of an operator induced by a translation. I believe that this does not help. My feeling is that I must find a semigroup of convolution defined by $T_tf = K_t*f$ where the kernel $P_t$ is a "semigroup" of some functions.

Comment: What I had in mind was $(T_{t}f)(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{i\alpha_{n}t}\hat{f}(n)e^{in x}$ where $\alpha_{n}$ are randomly-chosen real numbers. The problem I suppose is $p \ne 2$.